# How to Create an Azure Queue Storage Message when a Blob File is Uploaded/Updated?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am using Azure Storage Explorer to upload blob files into an Azure Storage Account. And would like to send a message to an Azure Storage Queue for every uploaded/updated file.

The message will contain the name of the file. These messages will be used by an Azure Webjob to identify which files to process.

How can this be accomplished? Is there a better way to do it?

**Note:** I am not using `BlobTrigger` inside the webjob because there is no guarantee that it will be notified by the trigger [(according to the documentation).](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger)

Comment: Unless Azure Storage Explorer has a way to place a message into a Queue for every new Blob, i don't see how you could accomplish this. Try to find the source code and extend either Microsoft's Azure Storage Explorer or this one - https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hello if we need to run a function every time a blob is uploaded and the blob name should be added to the queue. So in this scenario how to add message to queue every time blob is uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience, `BlobTrigger` would work as expected in my most cases. As the document you mentioned has stated as follows:

> If the **speed** and **reliability limitations** of blob triggers are not acceptable for your application, the recommended method is to create a queue message when you create the blob, and use the QueueTrigger attribute instead of the BlobTrigger attribute on the function that processes the blob.

As evilSnobu commented that there is no any in-build feature for you to send a message to Storage Queue when uploading blobs via Azure Storage Explorer. Based on your scenario, if you abandon `BlobTrigger`, I assume that you need to build your Web API or service for client-user to upload the file, then upload the user uploaded files to your Azure Storage and send a message (e.g. filename,etc.) to Storage queue in your back-end by yourself. At this point, the `QueueTrigger` would be triggered within your WebJob, and you could deal with the file (blob).